# Click on marker to open plot / data table

Tags: shiny, leaflet, action

I'm working on leaflet with shiny. The tools is basic, i have a map with some markers (coming from a table with LONG and LAT).

What I want to do is to open a table or a graph when i click on the marker.

Is there a simple way to do it?

Do you have a really simple example: you have a maker on a map, you click on the marker, and there is a plot or a table or jpeg that s opening?

Comment: This is relatively simple. Please take a look at the following example: http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/superzip-example.html ; after that, you can check the code here: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/tree/master/063-superzip-example  and specifically this js event handling file: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/blob/master/063-superzip-example/gomap.js

Answer (score 6):

Here is another example, [taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35267887/2381339) and a little bit adapted. When you click on a marker, the table below will change accordingly.

Apart from that, a good resource is this manual here:
https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html

```
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)
myData <- data.frame(
  lat = c(54.406486, 53.406486),
  lng = c(-2.925284, -1.925284),
  id = c(1,2)
)
ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("map"),
  p(),
  tableOutput("myTable")
)
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  data <- reactiveValues(clickedMarker=NULL)
  # produce the basic leaflet map with single marker
  output$map <- renderLeaflet(
    leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
      addCircleMarkers(lat = myData$lat, lng = myData$lng, layerId = myData$id)  
  )
  # observe the marker click info and print to console when it is changed.
  observeEvent(input$map_marker_click,{
    print("observed map_marker_click")
    data$clickedMarker <- input$map_marker_click
    print(data$clickedMarker)
    output$myTable <- renderTable({
      return(
        subset(myData,id == data$clickedMarker$id)
      )
    })
  })
})
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: @David Cheminet Does this work for you? You can store any information now inside the object `myData` as you have the `id` key linked to the marker.

Comment: Just replace the objects then. `myData` can be literally anything, if you want to display it in a table however, make sure it is a table/matrix/df object. Good luck!

Comment: This is a great example, but does clicking on a marker in a leaflet map only support renderTable? Can this be done for renderDataTable from DT?

Answer (score 1):

There is a leaflet example file here:

https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/blob/ca20e6b3a6be9d5e75cfb2fcba12dd02384d49e3/063-superzip-example/server.R

```
 # When map is clicked, show a popup with city info
  observe({
    leafletProxy("map") %>% clearPopups()
    event <- input$map_shape_click
    if (is.null(event))
      return()

    isolate({
      showZipcodePopup(event$id, event$lat, event$lng)
    })
  })
```

Online demo (see what happens when you click on a bubble):
http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/superzip-example.html

On the client side, whenever a click on a marker takes place, JavaScript takes this event and communicates with the Shiny server-side which can handle it as `input$map_shape_click`.

Comment: Well, I assume you have several markers on a leaflet map, right? `input$map_shape_click` is an object which contains further information about the object which has been clicked. I would recommend you provide your "clickable objects" (having markers as optical representations) with a unique id (uid) as well as more information. By having the uid, you can then access the other information as well.

Comment: For example, the example above opens a popup, but instead of a popup you could also modify some other output (table, plot etc)